# Restrict permissions to execute a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the context.

- two databases, database1 and database2.
- an asp.net web application that accesses database1 using user user1 (SQL Server authentication).
- a stored procedure sp1 in database1 that needs to modify some sensitive data in database2 through a stored procedure sp2 defined in database2. In other words sp1 calls database2..sp2.
- I created a SQL Server user2 login that is mapped to user2 in database1 and user2 database2. user2 in database2 has the permission to execute sp2.

I want user1 to be able to modify the database2 only through the sp1. I don't want user1 to be able to run: `exec database2..sp2`.

Here is some code that I tried:

```
USE [database2];
GO

SET  ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET  QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp2]
  WITH
  EXEC AS CALLER AS
SELECT current_user
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[sp2] TO [user2]
GO
```

In database1 I ran:

```
use database1
go      

drop procedure sp1
go

create procedure sp1 
as 

declare @m nvarchar(4000)

select current_user as usr

execute as login='user2'
begin try
execute database2.dbo.sp2 
end try
begin catch
  set @m = error_message()
  print @m
  revert
end catch

go

grant execute on dbo.sp1 to user1
go

execute as login='user1'
go

execute dbo.sp1

go
revert
go
```

Unfortunately this (i.e. `exec dbo.sp1` in the context of login='user1') doesn't work, it returns:

> Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "user2" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission

I also tried to compile sp1 with `with execute as 'user2'`, however, it doesn't work.

Is there another way I can make this work?

Thanks

Update:

If I run this:

```
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON User::user2 to [User1];  
GO
```

then the script works but it means User1 can now execute Database2..sp2.

What I want in a way is something like this: `grant impersonate on User::user2 to [sp1]`, i.e grant the impersonation permission to a procedure but I am not sure it's possible.

I found this [thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158609/giving-special-permissions-to-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server) which I think it is relevant to my case as well.

Answer (score 0):

ok, based on the [thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158609/giving-special-permissions-to-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server) I mentioned it is possible.

Here are the scripts to achieve this:

```
use database1
go

CREATE CERTIFICATE [PermissionsCert]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'WeakPassword'
WITH SUBJECT = 'Used to test granting permissions to code',
EXPIRY_DATE = '2099-12-31';

ADD SIGNATURE TO [dbo].[sp1]
  BY CERTIFICATE [PermissionsCert]
  WITH PASSWORD = 'WeakPassword';

BACKUP CERTIFICATE [PermissionsCert] TO FILE = 'k:\Sql_Backup\PermissionsCert.cer' 

use database2
go

CREATE CERTIFICATE PermissionsCert       
FROM FILE = 'k:\Sql_Backup\PermissionsCert.cer'  


CREATE USER [PermissionsUser] FROM CERTIFICATE [PermissionsCert];

grant execute on dbo.sp2 to [PermissionsUser]
go
```

I modified sp1 as follows:

```
alter procedure sp1 
as 
declare @m nvarchar(4000)

select current_user as usr

--execute as user='user2'
begin try
execute Database2.dbo.sp2 
end try
begin catch
  set @m = error_message()
  print @m
  revert
end catch

go
```

This works now:

```
execute as login='user1'
go

execute dbo.sp1

go
revert
go
```

However, this fails, which is what I want:

```
execute as login='user1'
go

execute database2.dbo.sp2

go
revert
go
```